# What kind of weapons are needed to deal with modern pirates

Tags: weapons

I know modern american destroyers use CIWS and VLS for their ships but what is needed for dealing with modern day piracy and any other non-military threats such as terrorism or cartels?

Comment: This looks like a question about factual matters.  You are on the wrong stack exchange.  Worldbuilding is for made up stuff.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  @Willk is correct.  per our [help/on-topic], WB.SE "is a site for designers, writers, artists, gamers and enthusiasts to get help creating imaginary worlds."  There's nothing imaginary about this.

Comment: So what is the right stack exchange for questions such as this.

Comment: So since it's not a detailed highly narrow physics question like the self charging pop gun and is not a reality check it cannot be answered?